# Scrolling QListView to keep items in view while inserting at start of list

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QListView with a model that I am inserting data into.  I'm inserting data at the start of the list which causes all the items in the view to scroll down.

What would be the best way to scroll the view automatically to keep the view fixed (i.e the view should move with the visible items as new items are inserted in the model)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work. The problem was not actually scrolling to the specific index - it was finding the correct index in the first place.

The following code scrolls the view to keep the same items in the view when inserting at the start of the list. It also checks if the view is at the top of the list and does not scroll in this case.

```
QScrollBar *pVerticalScrollBar = m_pUi->listView->verticalScrollBar();
bool bScrolledToTop = pVerticalScrollBar->value() == pVerticalScrollBar->minimum();
int iRowIndex = m_pUi->listView->indexAt(QPoint(8, 8)).row();
int iRowCount = m_pInfoListModel->rowCount();

/*
    insert text into m_pInfoListModel here
*/

// move scroll bar to keep current items in view (if not scrolled to the top)
if (bScrolledToTop == false)
{
    iRowCount = m_pInfoListModel->rowCount() - iRowCount;
    m_pUi->listView->scrollTo(m_pInfoListModel->index(iRowIndex + iRowCount, 0), QAbstractItemView::PositionAtTop);
}
```

This gives me a list of items that scroll by if I am at the top of the list, but when I wan't to look at items lower down the view stays fixed.

Comment: I'd recommend using `m_pUi->listView->model()` rather than `m_pInfoListModel`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could give `setAutoScroll(True)` to `QListView` instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

Find the list view item that I want to keep visible and than get its coordinates using

```
QRect QAbstractItemView::visualRect(const QModelIndex &index)
```

Than with the item's coordinates I will call `QScrollArea::ensureVisible(int, int, int, int)` function to keep the item visible after adding each new item to the list.

Comment: My problem was that I did not know the item index (see my answer)